# input quantity value not increasing on button click

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a web application developed in ASP.Net Web Forms with a block used for quantity input with bootstrap styling and running into problems.  The plus and minus do not work at all with incrementing the value or decrementing the value in the field.  Is there a solution to this I can use with bootstrap?

Quantity

```
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="minus-btn"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                </div>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity"  cssClass="form-control form-control-sm"  runat="server" value="1" min="1" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="plus-btn"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Have you write any javascript code on button click to increase/decrease quantity? If yes can you share ?

Comment: I don't have javascript code associated with it

Comment: see my answer below, you can use that code

Answer (score 1):

Use below JQuery code to increase/decrease quantity text box value

```
  function changeQuantity(type) {
        var currentQty = $("#txtQuantity").val();
        if (type == 'plus') {
            $("#txtQuantity").val(parseInt(currentQty, 10) + 1);
        }
        else {
              if((parseInt(currentQty, 10) - 1) < 0)
                $("#txtQuantity").val('0');  
              else{
                   $("#txtQuantity").val(parseInt(currentQty, 10) - 1);
        }
    }
```

and attach onclick event for buttons

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeQuantity('plus');" id="minus-btn">plus</button>
        </div>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity"  cssClass="form-control form-control-sm"  runat="server" value="1" min="1" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="plus-btn" onclick="changeQuantity('minus');">minus</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Arun.  Fixed the issue but now also accepts negative numbers.  Is there a way to remove the option from the minus button for negatives?

Comment: Edited my answer above. Simply add check for minus button click to check if value goes below 0 and set quantity back to 0

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to breadcrumbs I refactored some code advice from this thread and fixed my problem:

```
<script>
     function changeQuantity(type) {
        var currentQty = $("#txtQuantity").val();
        if (type == 'plus') {
            $("#txtQuantity").val(parseInt(currentQty, 10) + 1);
        }
        else if(currentQty < 2){
        $("#txtQuantity").val('1');
        }
         else{
            $("#txtQuantity").val(parseInt(currentQty, 10) - 1);
        }
    }
    </script>
```